# Truncating the Google spanner table without delete and recreating the table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

We are using Spanner db for staging large data set and we want to truncate the table on schedule basis. The table holds more than 25+ Million rows at anytime. we want to truncate the table without dropping and recreating it. What is the option in GCP to do it.

Currently we running Gcloud command manually with --enable-partitioned-dml option and which is timing out after deleting < 1M rows. Please suggest better way of doing it.

gcloud spanner databases execute-sql db-name --sql="delete from  tableName where SpannerCommitTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truncate is still not supported in Cloud Spanner. You could try Mutation.delete method with KeyRange or KeySet (as per your data)  to avoid the 20k mutations  limit.

To avoid manual work, you could write a Google Dataflow job which could read using SpannerIO from your table and then delete using SpannerIO.write for mutation or may be a custom PTransform (using mutatons.delete) to delete as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

1) The workaround for this would be to issue multiple simultaneous Partitioned DML deletes for different key ranges using a WHERE clause over a primary key. This would speed up the deletion.

2) "gcloud spanner databases execute-sql db-name" command also has a timeout option. Try increasing it to a higher value.
From the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/spanner/databases/execute-sql#--timeout), it looks like the default timeout is 10 minutes. So increasing this would help a bit.

Comment: Thank you .timeout option helped me :-0 while running manually using gcloud.